# ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((None, 6, 6, 2) vs (None,))

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, keras

So i was trying to make a pepsi recognizer (with Tensorflow 2.9.1) so if its pepsi it gives the highest number on the first output node and if it something else it gives a high number on the second output node, but for some reason I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xande\OneDrive\PycharmProjects\PythonCOPY\pepsi_recognition\main.py", line 25, in <module>
    model.fit(X, y, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.1, epochs=3)
  File "C:\Users\xande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\xande\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_file_qr2bi3f.py", line 15, in tf__train_function
    retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
ValueError: in user code:

    File "C:\Users\xande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1051, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\xande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1040, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\xande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1030, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\xande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 890, in train_step
        loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "C:\Users\xande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 948, in compute_loss
        return self.compiled_loss(
    File "C:\Users\xande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\compile_utils.py", line 201, in __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "C:\Users\xande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 139, in __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "C:\Users\xande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 243, in call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\xande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 1930, in binary_crossentropy
        backend.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits),
    File "C:\Users\xande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\backend.py", line 5283, in binary_crossentropy
        return tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=target, logits=output)

    ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((None, 6, 6, 2) vs (None,)).
```

and I don't know how to solve it, can someone please help?
Here is the code, the commented out section is what I used to turn the images into training data.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dense, Flatten
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import cv2 as cv
import random
import pickle

X = pickle.load(open("X.pickle","rb"))
y = pickle.load(open("y.pickle","rb"))

X = X/255.0

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, y, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.1, epochs=3)









# DATADIR = "C:/Users/xande/OneDrive/PycharmProjects/PythonCOPY/pepsi_recognition/nresized_dataset"
# CATEGORIES = ["Pepsi", "not Pepsi"]
# IMG_SIZE = 32
#
# training_data = []
#
#
# def create_training_data():
#     for category in CATEGORIES:
#         path = os.path.join(DATADIR, category)  # path to 'Pepsi' or 'Not Pepsi' dir
#         class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category)
#         for img in os.listdir(path):
#             try:
#                 img_array = cv.imread(os.path.join(path, img))
#                 new_array = cv.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
#                 training_data.append([new_array, class_num])
#             except Exception as e:
#                 pass
#
#
# create_training_data()
# random.shuffle(training_data)
#
# X = []
# y = []
#
# for features, label in training_data:
#     X.append(features)
#     y.append(label)
#
# X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)
# y = np.array(y)
#
# pickle_out = open("X.pickle","wb")
# pickle.dump(X, pickle_out)
# pickle_out.close()
#
# pickle_out = open("y.pickle","wb")
# pickle.dump(y, pickle_out)
# pickle_out.close()
```

Comment: You need to add flatten or one of the global pooling layers before the first dense layer, also your loss should have been `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`

Comment: Ah I see. I forgot to add that. Yea I thought there was a problem with the training data, because I had a problem before this which had to do with the training data, thanks BTW @Frightera